# USB WiFi stick: not detected as a WLAN device (0BDA:C811 Realtek AC)

Tags: wifi, realtek

I tried Ubuntu LTS and Fedora 37.

- On lshw, the Realtek device shows up as unclaimed.
- I can see the device using lsusb.
- I found some solution on the net about installed "linux-modules-extra" for Ubuntu but that package is not available for Ubuntu LTS.
- i found a suggestion that talks about modprobe and blacklist (also for Ubuntu) and same result.

Any more ideas? thanks

Comment: perhaps [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162974/wireless-usb-adapter-0bdac811-realtek-semiconductor-corp) or [this](https://tekbyte.net/installing-wifi-driver-for-realtek-802-11ac-on-linux-0bdac811/) or [this](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0bda-c811) ... there's many more if you search for linux drivers 0bda:c811

Comment: was hoping I don't have to compile a the driver in 2023 :D I'll check those out (I've seen those already in my initial search)

Comment: that's a problem with many USB wifi devices in Linux